# How do I deliver a message to a one subscriber of each group in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, mq

Say I have [this pub/sub](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) pattern implemented:

[image]

So basically I deliver a message to each `C`, who subscribed to exchange `X`.

I have instances of `P`, and a lot subscribers like C. Let's define C10, C11, C12, C13 as a group `C1` and C20, C21, C22, C23 as a group `C2`.

How do I deliver a message so only one `C` will receive a message from each group? (I'm perfectly fine with round robin)

Comment: So you want that one c2 message is received by only one of the C2n-s?

Comment: @cantSleepNow I want a message to be delivered to each group, one receiver per group (`cat` should be delivered to one of `mammals` (either `cat` or `dog` ...) AND to one of `sounds` (either `meow` or `roar` ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So appears what I needed was a `fanout` exchange with named queues instead of `exclusive` ones.

[image]

Each `C` service declares a non-exclusive named queue and binds it to the exchange. And binds a consumer to that queue.

If two services would declare a same queue, and bind a consumer to it, they end up being round-robin'ed.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this named vs. exclusive queues?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to [topics tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html).

Routing key should look like `C.C1` or `C.C2`.

Basically, send messages with routing key `C.*` ( so it they will go to `C.C1` xor `C.C2`) , and subscribe each consumer to `C.C1` xor `C.C2`. RMQ will distribute messages to all consumers subscribed to `C.CN` routing key in round-robin fashion.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but appears the answer is much easier. Also I didn't manage to send a message with a routing key `C.*` like you mentioned.